# Hydrogen atom orbital projections resemble to some Chladni figures! Mathematical reasoning?

Tags: acoustics, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen, orbitals

Chladni figures are formed by sprinkling salt on a vertically vibrating membrane, f.e. [[image: 1].

Some of them are purported to be projections of hydrogen atom orbitals f.e. 1s, 2s, 2p, 3d, etc., e.g. [image: 2].

One could bring it down to that the vibration patterns of Chladni figures are, as known, two-dimensional standing waves (this part is well established) and also to that -according to the Copenhagen (Born) interpretation- the hydrogen electron distribution also follows a (three-dimensional) standing wave pattern.

So far, so good, but what about the mathematical reasoning lying behind?

Could we claim that the two-dimensional Schrodinger equation for the hydrogen atom (i.e. the radial associated Laguerre polynomial, Ln) and the Chladni figures equation (i.e. the Bessel function of the first kind, Ja) are linear to each other? Any thoughts on the mathematical reasoning would be highly welcome.

Here is the complete list of relations between L and J I have come across: [image: 3]  and  [image: 4]  and  [image: 5]  and  [image: 6]  (P being the associated Legendre polynomial which is turned to a constant in a 2D problem) but does anyone see a valid explanation in any of these relations?

Comment: The shapes are not the same.

Answer (score 3):

After you separate out the time dependence (solution: oscillations), you get equations of the form

$$\nabla^2 f(\vec r) = Ef(\vec r)$$

where $f$ is something: displacement, a wave function. When the radial part is separated out, the disk (or drum head), looks like (a form of Bessel's equation):

$$ rf''(r) + f'(r)-Krf(r) = 0 $$

Meanwhile, the hydrogen atom can be reduced to Kummer's equation:

$$ xf''(r)+(b-x)f'-af = 0 $$

Similar, but different. In each case, the solutions are standing waves (but not sine and cosine). The azimuthal parts are identical: waves going in a circle: $e^{\pm im\phi}$ with integer $m$. Moreover, the more nodes in $r$, the larger $m$ can be.

So they look similar, as they  are standing waves, but on different shapes, with different spatial weighting.

A deeper study of the mathematical similarities would probably be found in hypergeometric functions, but that may be a math stack exchange question.

One final physics note: when one says "hydrogen orbitals", we generally think of Laguerre polynomials and spherical harmonics, thanks to the $SO(3)$ symmetry of the Coloumb hamiltonian. The problem also has a hidden $SO(4)$ symmetry that makes it separable in parabolic coordinates. The solutions are different orbitals that are equally valid....atoms don't care how we separate Schrödinger's equation. (This is why there is a double degeneracy: $SO(3)$ leads to degeneracy in $m$, while $SO(4)$ means the energy doesn't depend on $l$....only $n$ matters.).

Comment: *"When the radial part is separated out, the disk (or drum head), looks like (a form of Bessel's equation):*" Can you show or prove that? Or provide a reference to it? I'd have thought a drumhead would be different because the membrane is clamped at $r=R$, so $f(R)=0$ which is different for a plate.

Comment: @Gert I looked up wikipedia on waves on a drum. If boundary conditions are a problem, then my answer applies to the clamped Chladni set up. Regarding Bessel's equation: I am operating under the assumption that any 2nd order equation solved by Bessel's functions is a Bessel's equation.

Comment: *"then my answer applies to the clamped Chladni set up"* I don't think there is such a thing: the plates are excited at their boundary, so they can't be clamped there. But there is some similarity between  Chladni plates and SE solutions, that's true.

Comment: The transverse vibrations of a rigid plate (as used in Chladni figures) differ from those of a drumhead because the restoring force is due to the plate's rigidity, as opposed to the drumhead's tension. In particular, the analog of the Helmholtz equation for a thin rigid plate is $\nabla^4 f = \alpha f$ (i.e., the [biharmonic operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biharmonic_equation)), with $\alpha > 0$.  The solutions still work out to be Bessel functions, but you have to include modified Bessel functions in your modes as well.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ah yes, you are right about the biharmonic operator. I remember it now.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert that sound familiar, very interesting; however, pls read the 1st line of the question, esp _"membrane"_ .

Comment: @Gert on second thought: look at the circular figures. That outer node is awfully close the edge for an unclamped edge.

Comment: (This gallery images of Chladni figures pertain to free boundary plates. The clamped edge plates produce the same figures plus two fundamentals that are missing from the free edge plates. Otherwise, their figures are the same).

Comment: @CuriousOne:  Are the plates rigid, or are they membranes under tension?  This makes a difference (as I noted above) to the modes one would expect.

Comment: OK, OP shows the more interesting biharmonic open plate and then says _some_ of them (a membrane) look like orbits and then shows a rather standard set of drum heads that you can factor into radial/azimuth by looking at them. I addressed that in my answer....somewhat qualitatively.

Comment: @JEB OP's use of the term *membrane* is simply sloppy writing. His post is clearly about Chladni plates, not membranes. The displacements of circular membranes are here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane which are very different to the plates. The restoring forces are very different.

Comment: @Gert sloppy questions make for sloppy answers.

Comment: @JEB Sadly, at this 'science site' there's no shortage of poorly posed, poorly composed questions. =-( Good science requires good use of concise language but many here seem unaware of that.

Comment: @Gert well, it is a learning space, not the hallowed pages of _Physical Review Letters_ . Many an OP have been schooled on the importance of including units/dimensions, labels on figures, use of significant figures, which is good. Better here than in your 1st group meeting, or worse: conference presentation.

Comment: Anyway, for the eq. $\nabla^4 f = \alpha f$ in polar coordinates and no angular dependency (first column of the gallery) I get: $\alpha rf=2f''+3rf^{(3)}+r^2f^{(4)}$

Comment: Michael Seifert: These images pertain to metal plates, not, f.e. drum membranes. I understand the term "Chladni patterns" has come to pertain to all kind of substrates, f.e. drum membranes, water layers, soap bubbles, wood, plastic. However, empirically, I have acquired the belief that no matter the substrate, the patterns are the same, only under different frequencies, given that the shapes of the substrates are the same. Now, correct if wrong, but aren't the metal plates considered "membranes" of less but certainly adequate elasticity - adequate since vibrations occur and patterns emerge?

Comment: Gert: Don't the membrane vibrations from Wiki ( en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vibrations_of_a_circular_membrane) occur also in metal plates, however, at a less extent? Hasn't the mathematic description of both membranes and plates, today, come to be one and the same bringing out the Bessel function of first kind (Ja) in the time-independent part? This question aims to modify my thinking if otherwise.

Comment: Is there any thought on that the similarity in question can be attributed, to some similarity between the associated Laguerre polynomial (L) (involved in the Schrodinger equation of the hydrogen atom) and the Bessel of first kind (Ja) (involved in Chladni pattern equation)? If so, finding a linear relation between L and Ja would, perhaps, suffice?